# How to Display all associated subtask with specific taskId (Parent/Child relationship) --XAMARIN FORMS

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

I'm posting this question again because I didn't get the answer when I asked before ...This time I'm hoping I will get the answer I'm sharing the link of my Github repo:--     https://github.com/vishu2219/Todolist-new.git

And also the link of my question asked previously you can find code here also:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74560120/display-all-task-with-associated-subtask

I am new to Xamarin Forms and I am trying to create a task app. In the app, there will be the task list page and when the user selects a task, it will bring to the task view page. In the task view page, it will display the task details and the subtasks. The issue is that I can't figure out how to display the associated subtasks for the specific task id.

I'm Trying to make a todo task app with subtasks.

Comment: Posting a duplicate just because you didn’t get an answer the first time is against SO rules.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251422/my-question-never-got-answered-what-can-i-do